# Porting sklearn MLPClassifier to Keras with L2 regularization

Tags: keras, scikit-learn

I would like to port the following sklearn model to keras:

```
model = MLPClassifier(activation='tanh', hidden_layer_sizes=(60,50), alpha=0.001, random_state=42)
```

And what I have so far is:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras import regularizers
from tensorflow import set_random_seed

set_random_seed(42)

model = Sequential([
  Dense(60, activation='tanh'),
  Dense(50, activation='tanh'),
  Dense(1, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='sigmoid') 
])

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy', 'binary_accuracy'])

model.fit(
  x_train,
  y_train,
  epochs=200,
  batch_size=200,
  validation_data=(x_test, y_test)
)
```

But now I am struggling with the regularization term. The sklearn documentation is not too expressive on that:

> alpha : float, optional, default 0.0001
>     L2 penalty (regularization term) parameter.

But in keras the Dense layer has 3 properties for regularization.

> kernel_regularizer: Regularizer function applied to the kernel weights matrix (see regularizer).
>   bias_regularizer: Regularizer function applied to the bias vector (see regularizer).
>   activity_regularizer: Regularizer function applied to the output of the layer (its "activation").

Which one is actually equivalent to the sklearn regularization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the sklearn doc, the alpha parameter is used to regularize weights

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neural_networks_supervised.html

> Both MLPRegressor and MLPClassifier use parameter alpha for
>   regularization (L2 regularization) term which helps in avoiding
>   overfitting by penalizing weights with large magnitudes.

Keras lets you specify different regularization to weights, biases and activation values. Obviously, you can the same regularizer for all three.

Regularization is also applied on a per-layer basis, e.g.:

```
from keras import regularizers.l2
reg1 = l2(0.0001)
reg2 = l2(0.001)

model = Sequential([
  Dense(60, activation='tanh', kernel_regularizer=reg1, bias_regularizer=reg1, activity_regularizer=reg1),
  Dense(50, activation='tanh', kernel_regularizer=reg2, bias_regularizer=reg2, activity_regularizer=reg2),
  ...
```

Comment: `which helps in avoiding overfitting by penalizing weights` so basically you are saying I need to use bias + kernel regularisation but no activity regularisation

Comment: No, that's just an extract of the sklearn doc :) It's important to regularize activations, here's a good post on the topic: https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-reduce-generalization-error-in-deep-neural-networks-with-activity-regularization-in-keras/

Comment: but the question is not how to use regularization, the question is how to implement the exact same regularization behavior in keras as sklearn does it in MLPClassifier. Just quickly scanning your link section "MLP Activity Regularization", so it is actually only activity_regularizer

Comment: Looking at the sklearn code, it seems the regularization is applied to the weights: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/neural_network/_multilayer_perceptron.py#L232